# Dojo Button doesn't "look" disabled?

Tags: javascript, button, dojo

I'm relatively new to JS and Dojo.

I have a button created declaratively:

```
<button id="${ns}submitButton" name="submitButton" type="button" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Submit Request</button>
```

and code in my javascript that gets that button and disables it.

```
self._cancelButton = registry.byId(ns+'cancelButton');
self._submitButton.set('disabled', true);
```

When I do this, the button is, in fact, disabled - if I click on it, it won't submit. And if I change the "true" to "false", I *can* submit just fine. The problem is that the button doesn't *look* like it's disabled. It looks just like the other button. Is the code designed to only modify the behavior and not the appearance or am I missing something? Is there a simple way to make it *look* disabled? (ex. grayed out or something along those lines?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should look grayed out: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjcvL/

Comment: Have you added the **claro** theme to your dojo?